# How to downgrade the dependencies for npm packages in StackBlitz?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I'm trying to create an app for demo propose on StackBlitz and must use Angular 5.2.x because my app is still using 5.2.x. I just can't downgrade from v6 to v5.2 when I try to install the dependencies.

I actually need e.g. `"@angular/common": "^5.2.10", "rxjs": "^5.5.10", "@angular/http": "^5.2.10"` etc. But it just force me to install the v6.

Is there a possibilities to avoid this and install the needed versions or there is no way?

Have been checking the doc for Stackblitz, but didn't find something talking about such case.

Comment: If you go to dependencies, where it says 'enter package name' and type @angular/common@5.2.10 or rxjs@5.5.10 and hit enter it should work

Comment: Yes, true. My bad. Forgot and was trying @http/common 5.2.10 which will never works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Delete the existing package by clicking the trash can when hovering over the package:
Where it says `enter package name` type `@angular/common@5.2.10` and click enter.

The package will be installed. Repeat for `rxjs@5.5.10` and `@http/common@5.2.10`

Comment: The same here. My mistake! Forgot and was trying @http/common 5.2.10 which will never works.

Comment: It looks like you can also just type `@angular/common@5.2.10` and click enter and it will override the other version

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the best way is to generate an angular project with the version you want and host it at github then browser the project online at `StackBlitz` ,It 's look like import an angular project.

read more about this [Run Angular CLI repos directly in your browser](https://blog.angular.io/run-angular-cli-repos-directly-in-your-browser-41332fd80901)

Comment: Would be a better option!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to connect a stackblitz project to a github repository, install Angular and your dependencies locally and push it. After that your repository is available on Stackblitz with all correct dependencies and configurations.

1. Create a new Github repository online.
2. Locally create a new Angular App using angular-cli with a specific version e.g. `npx @angular/cli@13 new stackblitz`
3. Go to the project using `cd stackblitz`
4. Run the commands as recommended by Github for pushing existing repository as recommended on the new created repository.
5. Create a new stackblitz Angular project.
6. Click on "Connect to repository" on the top left corner.

[image]

7. Click on "import existing repository".

[image]

8. Stackblitz pulls automatically the changes from the github repository.