# Can't find packages in stackblitz, even though it is present in npm website. How to install then?

Tags: polymer-3.x, stackblitz

I was installing dependencies for polymer app in stackblitz. It said 3 packages could not be found, but ther were present in npm website.
I tried cdn also. Even that did not work.

**Screenshots:**

[image: error in stackblitz]
[image: package already present in npm]

I have also installed [CDN from this website](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@polymer/iron-ajax) in `external sources` of stackblitz.

Please help where am i going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i was trying to install as `@polymer/iron-ajax`. it could not install. Adding version after the package works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632971/how-to-downgrade-the-dependencies-for-npm-packages-in-stackblitz) helped me.
Installing like: `@polymer/iron-ajax@3.0.0-pre.21` worked for me.